# Syntax error in a turbo c++ program

Tags: c++, function, syntax, compiler-errors, turbo-c++

I get declaration syntax error in my code but i do not find any mis-typings or anything.Please help.I am using turbo c++ for my school level programming.
I get it where i have typed -void issue() (inside the main function)

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class book {
    char bookname[20];
    char isbn[20];
    char author[20];
    char category[20];
    float price;
    int noc;

  public:

    void accept(){
        cout<<"Enter book name :- \n";
        gets(bookname);
        cout<<"Enter isbn no of the book:- \n";
        gets(isbn);
        cout<<"Enter authour name:- \n";
        gets(author);
        cout<<"Enter category of book:- \n";
        gets(category);
        cout<<"Enter price of the book :- \n";
        cin>>price;
        cout<<"Enter no of copies of book available in the library :- \n";
        cin>>noc;
    }

    void display() {
        cout<<"Name of the book is :- ";puts(bookname);cout<<endl;
        cout<<"ISBN :- ";puts(isbn);cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Author :- ";puts(author);cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Category :- ";puts(category);cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Price :- ";cout<<price<<endl;
        cout<<"No of copies available :- ";cout<<noc<<endl;
    }

    void issue();

}b[5];


int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i) {
        b[i].accept();
    }

    void issue() {
        int flag=1;
        char booksearch[20];
        cout<<"Enter name of book member wants to issue :- \n";
        gets(booksearch);
        for(int i=0;i<5;++i) {
            flag=strcmp(booksearch,b[i].bookname);
            if(flag==0)
                break;
        }

        if(flag==0) {
            cout<<"Book found \n";
            b[i].display();
            b[i].issue();
        } else {
            cout<<"Book not available:- \n";
        }

    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining `issue` inside `main`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `main` does not have a closing brace Put one in before `void issue()`
2. Now change `void issue()` to `void book::issue()`

Fix this then tell us any further errors along with the line that it occurs on

**EDIT**

Instead of 1) move

```
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

To that location

Comment: b[5] is an array of objects for class book, anyways i tried doing it  the usual way but has same results.          2)i have created the issue function inside main function, isn't it valid?

Comment: I did notice that and updated my answer. It would help if you sort out the indentation

Comment: @JonnyHenly (1) Fixes this by putting the closing brace in for `main`

Comment: @JonnyHenly if could help me moving issue out of main :)

Comment: @HarshAdwani do what this answer says - cut all of `void issue() { ... }` and paste it outside of `int main() { ... }`, then add `book::` in front of `issue()` to form `void book::issue() { ... }`. Then compile and report if any other errors occur.